# error when trying to build node.js in windows

Tags: visual-studio-2008, node.js, window

im trying to build node.js but i have problem .
i downloaded 2 versions one from git and one from the site
my configuration is :
Python 3.2.2
visual studio express 2008
windows xp 32bit

the errors when running vcbuild.bat:
**joyent-node-v0.7.7-49-g06ada03:**

```
  File "configure", line 344
    print "creating ", filename
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Failed to create vc project files.
```

**node-v0.6.15**

```
 File "tools\gyp_node", line 20
    print 'Error running GYP'
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Failed to create vc project files.
```

what im doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use python2.6 or 2.7 according to the [installation guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) in the wiki.

Comment: also need visual studio 2010 , do you know if i can build node in  eclipse cdt and mingw on windows?

Comment: You could use VS10 Express, which is free. I don't use mingw but you could give cygwin a try?

Comment: yeah i know im compiling now with 2010 express.

Comment: Was using Python 3.1. Downgraded to 2.7 and it worked.